# Indipendence between a random variable $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R^d$ a random variable.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$.

I read that $X$ and $\mathcal F$ are indipendent iff 
$$
\Bbb E[\phi(X)\chi_D]=\Bbb E[\phi(X)]P(D)
$$
for every $D\in\mathcal F$ and for every continous and bounded $\phi:\Bbb R^d\to \Bbb R$.

How can we see this?

Here's my try: by definition, $X$ and $\mathcal F$ are indipendent iff the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal F$ are such and this happens iff for every $A\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R^d)$ and $D\in\mathcal F$
\begin{equation}
P(X\in A,D)=P(X\in A)P(D)\;.
\end{equation}
Now this is trivial if $P(D)=0$, thus let's suppose $P(D)>0$; in this way the last equation can be rewritten as
$$
P(X\in A\vert D)=P(X\in A)\;.
$$
Let now denote ($D$ fixed) $Q(B):=P(B|D)$ which is another probability on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$.

Thus $X$ and $\mathcal F$ are indipendent iff
$$
Q(X\in A)=P(X\in A)
$$
for every $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R^d)$ (and for every $D\in\mathcal F$), which is equivalent to say that the distributions $\mu:=P^X$ and $\nu:=Q^X$ on $(\Bbb R^d,\mathcal B(\Bbb R^d))$ are the same; but this is true iff for every continous and bounded $\phi:\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R$ we have that
$$
\int\phi\,d\mu=\int\phi\,d\nu\;.
$$
But now it's clear that that
$$
\int\phi\,d\mu=\int\phi\,dP^X=\Bbb E[\phi(X)]
$$
and similarly
$$
\int\phi\,d\nu=\int\phi\,dQ^X=\widetilde{\Bbb E}[\phi(X)]
$$
where the $\widetilde{\Bbb E}$ denotes the mean value one the probability space $(\Bbb R^d,\mathcal B(\Bbb R^d),Q^X)$.

Thus $X$ and $\mathcal F$ are indipendent iff
$$
\Bbb E[\phi(X)]=\widetilde{\Bbb E}[\phi(X)]
$$
so now, to conclude I should rewrite $\widetilde{\Bbb E}[\phi(X)]$ in function of $\Bbb E[\phi(X)]$, getting the dipendence from $D$ explicit.

But I don't know how to go on.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making the proof more complicated than necessary. The first part of your proof shows that for $\phi=1_A$ (indicator function of $A$), you have:
$$ E( 1_A \circ X \cdot 1_D) = P(X\in A,D)=P(X\in A) P(D)=E(1_A\circ X) P(D)$$
The equality of the first and the last expression then also holds for linear combinations of indicator functions, whence for any measurable $\phi$ such that $\phi\circ X$ is in $L^1$, in particular for $\phi$ continuous and bounded.